# Google Colab, module not found when running python script

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a Colab notebook open and have my files cloned from a github repo. I want to run a python script called `models.py`. In this file, I am using pandas. When I run this line in Colab:

```
!python3 models.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

However, if I run in a cell on Google Colab:

```
!pip3 list
```

I find that pandas is indeed installed:

```
pandas                   0.25.3
```

My assumption is that when I run the script, it is not able to see the libraries I have installed but I am unsure how to fix this issue.

If I run:

```
!which python3
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

The python file I am trying to run is under:

```
/content/my_project/models.py
```

Should I instead take a different approach to running this file?

Comment: restart the kernel

Comment: Just tried this and still getting same error

Comment: try pip install pandas

Comment: Tried this and restarted kernel, not working still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a clean Colab runtime, the location of python 3 is different than what you show in your question:

```
!which python3
# /usr/bin/python3
```

It looks like you are installing another Python instance in your VM. To ensure you're using Colab's bundled Python 3 executable, try using

```
!/usr/bin/python3 models.py
```

If you actually want to use the new python instance you've installed, you'll have to also install whatever packages you need. For example

```
!/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
!python3 models.py
```

You can use

```
%run models.py
```